# How to calculate days to months in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate days to month like below

[Like this:](https://www.google.ae/search?client=opera&q=days%20to%20month&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=m7mjWoOgJIfv8Afck5rADw)

I am using this code to get months:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2017-12-06'

SELECT
    CAST(DATEDIFF(M, @Date, GETDATE()) AS varchar) + ' Months and ' + 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(D, @Date, DATEADD(M, - DATEDIFF(M, @Date, GETDATE()), GETDATE())) AS varchar) + ' Days'
```

Output:

```
(Result)
3 Months and 4 Days
```

It works but I need output like this

```
90 days + 4 days = 94days
```

Expected output:

```
Month=3.09041
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On average, a month has 30.43 days (365.25 / 12).  How about just doing this?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(days, @Date, GETDATE()) / (365.25 / 12)
```

This does not produce your exact results but it is a very good estimate of decimal months.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, 94 Days converted to months is 3.09041.

This code will produce the output:

```
DATEDIFF(DD, @Date, GETDATE()) / 30.4375 % 12
```

*Note: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2019*